# Pauli Exclusion Principle with two electrons in box

Tags: pauli-exclusion-principle

Suppose that I measure the spin of two electrons in the z direction, and that they have the same spin. Then we put both electrons in a box. After a long time, we know nothing about the spatial distribution of the electrons in the box, so their spatial distributions are equal. But their spins in the z direction are still equal. This seems to contradict the Pauli Exclusion Principle. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Why do you believe the two electrons will be in the same state (where Pauli exclusion would be a factor)?

Comment: "After a long time... their spatial distributions are equal." Why? And why would "a long time" only affect the spatial distribution and not the spin distribution?

Comment: "This seems to contradict the Pauli Exclusion Principle. How can this be resolved?" It is resolved because your premise is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would we know nothing?  If you place the electrons in an antisymmetric spatial state, say
$$
\psi_{12}(x_1,x_2)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_1(x_1)\psi_2(x_2)-\psi_2(x_1)\psi_1(x_2)\right)
$$
so the full spatial+spin state is antisymmetric as required by Pauli:
$$
\psi_{12}(x_1,x_2)\vert \uparrow\rangle_1\vert\uparrow\rangle_2
$$
then the state will evolve
$$
\Psi(x_1,x_2,t)=e^{-i t E_{12}/\hbar}
\psi_{12}(x_1,x_2)\vert \uparrow\rangle_1\vert\uparrow\rangle_2
$$
so the distribution is well known.

Even if you use a linear combination of antisymmetric states:
$$
\psi(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{ij}c_{jk} \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_k(x_1)\psi_j(x_2)
-\psi_j(x_1)\psi_k(x_2)\right)
$$
the time evolution will be given by
$$
\sum_{ij}c_{jk}  e^{-i E_{jk}t/\hbar}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_k(x_1)\psi_j(x_2)
-\psi_j(x_1)\psi_k(x_2)\right)\vert\uparrow\rangle_1\vert\uparrow\rangle_2
$$
which is still (legitimately) antisymmetric.